# Trouble with the google analytics api

Tags: c#, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I want to access to my site data on a console aplication.

But the only way (that I know) to access the data is with the tableId; can I get the data using the Web Property ID?

the "tableId" is not easy to know, and I dont want to get it from the querystring. So I want to access the information with the "Web Property ID".

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the profile id using this tool provided by google: http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/

Just log in with your credentials and you will receive a dropdown of all your properties and all their profile Ids.